# Show that group with precisely two subgroups must have prime order

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Suppose group $G$ has precisely two subgroups.  Show that $|G|$ is prime.  $|G|$ denotes the order of the group $G$.

If I let $g\leq G$ and $k\leq G$. I know that $G^p=e$ where $e$ is the identity element of $G$.

Would someone please give me an idea how this question goes?

Comment: what is $g,k$????????// and $G^p$

Comment: Do you know Lagrange's Theorem?

Comment: Hint: Let $a\ne e$. Look at the subgroup generated by $a$. By assumption it is all of $G$, so $G$ is cyclic. Now show that a cyclic group (finite or infinite) of order $\gt 1$ whose order is not prime has a proper subgroup.

Comment: Lagrange's theorem, that If $G$ is a finite group, and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $|G|$ is divisible by $|H|$, proves the converse, that if the order of $G$ is prime, then $G$ has only two subgroups.  That does not show that if $G$ has only two subgroups then the order of $G$ must be prime!

Comment: would you assume that I have not gone over either cyclic group or Lagrange's theorem

Answer (score 2):

If $G$ has precisely two subgroups, they must be the trivial ones and order of $G \geq 2$. So take any $a \in G$ with $a \neq e$, then $\langle a \rangle = G$. Let $n$ be the order of $a$ (which is the order of $G$). Suppose $n$ is not prime, then there's $k,l \gt 1$ with $n = k \cdot l$. But then the element $a^k$ generates a subgroup $\langle a^k \rangle$ of order $l$ (because $(a^k)^l = a^{kl} = a^n = e$). However $1 \lt l \lt n = ord(G)$. This contradicts that $G$ has only trivial subgroups.

Comment: would you assume that I have not  gone over either  cyclic group or 
 
Lagrange's theorem

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Can you further explain your question?

Comment: I meant I have not taken cyclic group and  Lagrange's theorem.  so , if you would write me a prove just make sure that your not using the fact that I know either cyclic group or Lagrange's theorem. The question was if I have a group G. This group has exactly two subgroup. Then then the order of G it should be prime. I was thinking that G , should have the identity e and G itself. but I have no idea how it related to a prime.   Thank you so much

Comment: @ADAM I haven't explicitly used the Lagrange theorem. But that a single element in a group generates a subgroup – are you aware of that? If yes, then it should be clear. The notation $\langle a \rangle$ means just $\{e, a, a^2, a^3, ...\}$

Comment: Thank you. I know what cyclic group is but I would like not to use it.

Comment: What is the reason for that? Unfortunately I cannot think of a proof without using the fact that an element withing $G$ generates a cyclic subgroup which mus be already $G$.

Comment: this question is given from the professor before we went over cyclic group. so we have been asked to answer this question without using the definition of cyclic group.

Comment: by the way, the question has not mentioned if G is finite or infinite. would you have any idea how would I proof that the order of G < $\infty$

Comment: Prove that $\{k \in \mathbb{Z}\ |\ a^k \}$ is a subgroup for $a \in G, a \neq e$. Then look at the homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \to \ G$, where $k \mapsto a^k$ (prove that it's a homomorphism). $G$ only has its trivial subgroups, so $\phi$ is surjective. Suppose order of $G$ is infinite. Then $ker(G) = \{0\}$, thus $\phi$ is isomorphism and $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. But $2\mathbb{Z}$ is a nontrivial subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$.